# Subsonic 3, SimpleRepository, SQL Server: How to find rows with a null field?

Tags: sql-server, subsonic3, simplerepository

How ca I use Subsonic's `Find<T>` method to search for rows with a field containing the "null" value. For the sake of the discussion, let's assume I have a c# class called "Visit" which contains a nullable DateTime field called "SynchronizedOn" and also let's assume that the Subsonic migration has created the corresponding "Visits" table and the "SynchronizedOn" field.

If I was to write the SQL query myself, I would write something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Visits WHERE SynchronizedOn IS NULL
```

When I use the following code:

```
var visits = myRepository.Find<Visit>(x => x.SynchronizedOn == null);
```

Subsonic turns it into the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM Visits WHERE SynchronizedOn == null
```

which never returns any rows.

I tried the following code but it throws an error:

```
visits = repository.Find<Visit>(x => x.SynchronizedOn.HasValue);
```

I was able to use the following syntax:

```
var query = from v in repository.All<Visit>()
            where v.SynchronizedOn == null
            orderby v.CreatedOn
            select v;
visits = query.ToList<Visit>();
```

but it's not as nice an short as using the `Find<T>` method.

Anyone knows how I can specify the "SynchronizedOn IS NULL" condition in the `Find<T>` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var visits = myRepository.All<Visit>().Where(x => x.SynchronizedOn == null).ToList();
```

Comment: Your suggestion is an improvement on my linq query but not using the Find<T> method. Should I understand that the Find<T> method is unable to check for null?