# SubSonic SimpleRepository Find Method with nullable DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, subsonic, lambda

```
using SubSonic3 SimpleRepository;
```

I have a table used for an email queue which has a SentOn DATETIME column that allows nulls. Using the following Lambda expressions have yielded me errors, does anyone have any ideas how to select a list from the table were the column is null.

```
IList<Email> emails = _repo.Find<Email>(x => x.SentOn == null);
IList<Email> emails = _repo.Find<Email>(x => !x.SentOn.HasValue);
IList<Email> emails = _repo.Find<Email>(x => x.SentOn.Value.Equals(null));
```

Surely there is a simple way to achieve this, not like it's a edge case. I think my limited lambda/linq knowledge is the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the error you encounter I'm guessing it is because you are writing LINQ code to be executed by C# but you are passing it to SubSonic to convert it into SQL.

A solution [is in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249944/subsonic-3-simplerepository-sql-server-how-to-find-rows-with-a-null-field) which basically involves querying the SQL db for all results then using a LINQ query within C# after.

Alternatively you should be able to do a (pseudocode) `.Where(fieldName).IsNull` similar to SubSonic 2.0